Return status 404 when trying to download PDF's from links
I have a .csv file that contains links to some PDF files. When pressed, these links automatically start to download the file (one example of such link would be https://rei.gov.ro/teza-doctorat-document/82405e69f7a7a04f8-TEZA-DOCTORAT-AGNES-GAZDAC-semnat-.pdf).
My attempts of building a python script to download all of them return 404. I want to understand why this is happening and to see if I can find a solution to this problem
csv = 'links.csv'  
df = pd.read_csv(csv)

def download_pdf(url, file_name):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        response.raise_for_status() 
        with open(file_name, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(response.content)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(e)

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    url = row['Link']
    file_name = f'file_{i + 1}.pdf'
    download_pdf(url, file_name)


Have you tried printing the URL before each request? Are they indeed correct?

@OrfeoTerkuci, I just tried, and it seems to me that the URLS are correct here Is the output for the first link:
https://rei.gov.ro/teza-doctorat-document/82405e69f7a7a04f8-TEZA-DOCTORAT-AGNES-GAZDAC-semnat-.pdf 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://rei.gov.ro/teza-doctorat-document/82405e69f7a7a04f8-TEZA-DOCTORAT-AGNES-GAZDAC-semnat-.pdf

the example link you provided does not exist and returns a 404

@TeejayBruno I get the same return when trying in python. But, accessing it through a browser would start the download of the document. Let me know if this is not the case

@KJ thank you very much for your explanation. Using this, I've tried a selenium-based approach which accesses the main site first, and after starts downloading the files using the links.
